# How to know when a day was started in android?

Tags: android, datetime, android-service, android-broadcast

Is there a way to detect when a day was started or date or time changes (not changed by user, it is changed by system). Any `BroadCastReciever` to do it? I am using service to run it by every hour, But drains battery.

My requirement is to check when the day has started (when time changes to 12 AM) or time changes (hourly) I want to display the `notification`.

Answer (score 4):

Create alarm set on a specified time say 00 hours in your case, using AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver. And you will receive a brodcast on every new day.

```
 private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

For further reference :
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-alarm-set-on-specified-time.html

Answer (score 1):

or you can use ScheduledExecutorService to schedule and execute a task http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple to do.

**Step 1**

Use the AlarmManager to fire up a BroadcastReceiver periodically..

```
private void showNotification() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 50000, pendingIntent);
}
```

**Step 2**

In the `onReceive()` do the checking when the time is 00 hours of the day, create a notification and show it.

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

        // This is where you check when you want to show the notification
        if(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 0){
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_box_title))
                    .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.message_timesheet_not_up_to_date));


            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Do forgot to register the custom BroadcastReceiver is Manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.example.NotificationReceiver"
        android:process=":remote" />
```

Comment: Sorry, took some time for me to write the detailed answer. Please let me know if I can help in any other way.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Or do you need any more help?